# How to crop images Pointer mouse move follow area crop UWP

Tags: uwp-xaml

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7buYy.jpg)

How to crop images pointer mouse follow area crop sample picture

Answer (score 0):

In UWP, you can use the `ImageCropper` control to meet your needs:

- [ImageCropper XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/imagecropper)
- [Source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/ImageCropper)

Use like this:

```xml
<Page ...
     xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"/>
    <controls:ImageCropper x:Name="ImageCropper" />
</Page>
```

```cs
await ImageCropper.LoadImageFromFile(file);
ImageCropper.CropShape = CropShape.Circular;
using (var fileStream = await someFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite, StorageOpenOptions.None))
{
    await _imageCropper.SaveAsync(fileStream, BitmapFileFormat.Png);
}
```